# Quantum Representation of the Brouwer problem

Tags: quantum-algorithms, oracles

Brouwer’s fixpoint theorem guarantees a point, $x_0$, such that $f(x_0)=x_0$ for any continuous $f$ that maps a simplex (N dimensional triangle) to itself.

In his presentation of the PPAD complexity class, [Papadimitriou](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272574/1-s2.0-S0022000005X80588/1-s2.0-S0022000005800637/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDRNn0QjcHQ%2BQlww1%2B4MCgNqzDXher0QBn1HQKgeujEdAiEA8ilsHMgMod16EoL7b9RqXtlcLmzmWhf%2FtzcyGiFeTScq1QQI3P%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDCqVhVDHEY76uXqWDiqpBL4ZpmMmIflt27cKElGWXAnfZBYAP4dqgvsz4nYhtwY71CWrS6bc%2Fa2V2PfLhWAVW%2BXsp%2FUIBb4VAxi29yguJH3Zk3xlE4IJ7OoprhIExVHmh101ux3MDwiTZS4ksl3ArQQAZmqC3wkTqb8gE%2FqM3Bttwbiu1tU%2FNtMRcZyIZhlCXcWabcduECjt1XLCxia0lIZJxpyRq4bwppUP1FCZBHTF8aRaXiK6%2BPlFsx6vOg3Ridz0w%2BuBQCFba8TA1eCG9aqZZAc0iaV6nWKo197XPGix739mksr0%2F3U5PdpCx0enkgHT%2FCGcnYr06ZLdSoAlnTbfCGrnRXtLiUjGE5pRZEUUmhVmgkdc9MftiivaPYJcgzmWJY3mt%2BCBt4cZ9QOHV1AfzYrGdfg5l%2FaMMUK5IjrHEYHR40GrShkXmNvD6eQr%2FIWCHLpqIVuqUFwMcuUWu4YOkPQoOZXK%2Bki4nCPwavj5p1qRV0omJoAGypW6Gpg8AmuwIrKUbCGL%2Flw1Lir5jDAttL9k6ZaIqm42oEuZhEY%2BuQy63HXlfgDzbz0FkPCoGMCWSCPH9wKc0iEKVyWp55JU30aRTT6coSVkO%2BvkDgV72SSOVnCwiKeki5%2FqEeqfTWFG3bjzUiQYr5DYM1%2Fb6cRAxCtKPlSc5f6NNbBSIe1FulrC9q1%2F2UVWzprY%2F2sQU1eAzN6AdpIVsYCGOVi1OCNe3esF76XM2rrcvNGG0IsYsk%2F1r%2F51Ju4wkavonAY6qQHNnr%2BPQFhpOVxLH6haEszgtOzR5QJYQ%2Bi3gqyTfAPTH9am6kSBYW7nn5HRX40zHabVccpUGUEDBOMPze76iez8DOPFJzZBPAHHf%2Bi6aKrqxvmali6tJdrIsMj4qT9n%2FxoxeF3DtPFlrA%2Fyd3wJDs5mRHx4Ycq8%2FquwByk72tO%2FgrbpVgbjkqDzLPCWRtDcyELIPRSRUZv5zSsJs%2FuE9xcZahOzT6%2BqVWCP&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20221214T185339Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWOOGJG7R%2F20221214%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d2a4f849288785b2f64713ad7c3bc3ac034f890f07f49c1deb052f05dfbc208b&hash=fecb6d700d1f0c72af6e6cfd03181ce2da5f3d22690247b5b2b946a765d1cb8a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022000005800637&tid=spdf-6d5b03c0-1b52-49d7-b15b-a9c1f59c12e2&sid=cecc7b6185aa324aeb0a3d3-3796098e0fdegxrqa&type=client&ua=51545c585c5b06575b57&rr=779924c089732376) presents a problem: $\texttt{Brouwer}$. Given a Turing machine (with discrete inputs) that calculates this function, $f$, calculate the approximate fixpoints.

My question is this: How can this be represented quantum mechanically. We can encode $f$ with an oracle, but will this still be PPAD complete? If not, how can we call this Turing machine with a quantum computer? Can we use a Quantum Turing Machine; and will this be PPAD complete?